# Return dim3 variable from function in CUDA C++

Tags: c++, cuda

I would like to return a dim3 object from a function.
The specific code is:

```
dim3 getGridBasedOnBlockSize(int width, int height, int block_size) {
    int gridX = (int)ceil((float)width / block_size);
    int gridY = (int)ceil((float)height / block_size);
    return dim3(gridX, gridY);
```

But while compiling an error occurs:

```
error: expected expression before ‘dim3’
 return dim3(gridX, gridY);
        ^
```

So I changed it a little bit to this:

```
dim3 getGridBasedOnBlockSize(int width, int height, int block_size) {
    int gridX = (int)ceil((float)width / block_size);
    int gridY = (int)ceil((float)height / block_size);
    dim3 gridXY(gridX, gridY);
    return gridXY;
```

But now it says:

```
error: incompatible types when returning type ‘dim3 (*)() 
{aka struct dim3 (*)()}’ but ‘dim3 {aka struct dim3}’ was expected
 return gridXY;
        ^
```

Could you help me? What does this mean, how can I fix this in order to be compiled properly with nvcc? Thank you!

The complete code for this .c file is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#define WARP_SIZE 16
#define DEBUG false

float *_copyHostDevice(float *src, int src_size) {
  float *src_d;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&src_d, sizeof(float) * src_size);
  cudaMemcpy(src_d, src, sizeof(float) * src_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  return src_d;
  }

float *_copyDeviceHost(float *src, int src_size, float *dst) {
   float *target;
   if (dst == NULL) {
      target = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * src_size);
   } else {
      target = dst;
     }

   cudaMemcpy(target, src, sizeof(float) * src_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   return target;
   }

typedef struct {
   int x;
   int y;
} GlobalDim;

__device__ GlobalDim getGlobalDim(dim3 blockDim, dim3 blockIdx, dim3    threadIdx) {
    GlobalDim gd;
    gd.x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    gd.y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    return gd;
}

dim3 getGridBasedOnBlockSize(int width, int height, int block_size) {
   int gridX = (int)ceil((float)width / block_size);
   int gridY = (int)ceil((float)height / block_size);
   dim3 gridXY(gridX, gridY);
   return gridXY;
}


void _sleep(int n) {
   usleep(n*1000000);
}

void drawMatrix(float *m, int width, int height) {
   for (int i=0; i < height; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < width; j++) {
          printf("%f ", m[i * width + j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

And the compile command and result:

```
$ nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -o project4 nn.cu parallel.cu utils.c
  utils.c: In function ‘getGridBasedOnBlockSize’:
  utils.c:48:5: warning: parameter names (without types) 
  in function    declaration
   dim3 gridXY(gridX, gridY);
   ^
  utils.c:49:12: error: incompatible types when returning  
   type ‘dim3 (*)() {aka struct dim3 (*)()}’ but ‘dim3 {aka struct dim3}’    was expected
 return gridXY;
        ^
```

And for the dim3(...) case, it shows:

```
nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -o project4 nn.cu parallel.cu utils.c
  utils.c: In function ‘getGridBasedOnBlockSize’:
  utils.c:48:12: error: expected expression before ‘dim3’
    return dim3(gridX, gridY);
        ^
```

Edit1:
@Zindarod

Using

```
dim3 gridXY;
gridXY.x = gridX;
gridXY.y = gridY;
return gridXY;
```

instead of

```
dim3 gridXY(gridX, gridY);
    return gridXY;
```

as you suggested, unfortunately throws this error:

```
$ nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -o project4 nn.cu parallel.cu utils.c
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `_copyHostDevice':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x16): multiple definition of `_copyHostDevice'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x16): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `_copyDeviceHost':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8c): multiple definition of `_copyDeviceHost'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8c): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `getGlobalDim':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xed): multiple definition of `getGlobalDim'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xed): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `getGridBasedOnBlockSize':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x120): multiple definition of `getGridBasedOnBlockSize'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x120): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `_sleep':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1de): multiple definition of `_sleep'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1de): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `drawMatrix':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): multiple definition of `drawMatrix'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `setWeightsForLayers(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x27b): multiple definition of `setWeightsForLayers(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x27b): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `updateWeightsCUDA(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x885): multiple definition of `updateWeightsCUDA(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x12b2): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `update_layer(float*, float*, int, int, float*)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3fa): multiple definition of `update_layer(float*, float*, int, int, float*)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3fa): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `mapStepCUDA(float*, float*, float*, int, int)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x9ad): multiple definition of `mapStepCUDA(float*, float*, float*, int, int)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x13da): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `reduceStepCUDA(float*, float*, int, int)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xa9d): multiple definition of `reduceStepCUDA(float*, float*, int, int)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x14ca): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `__device_stub__Z17updateWeightsCUDAPfS_S_S_ii(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x77a): multiple definition of `__device_stub__Z17updateWeightsCUDAPfS_S_S_ii(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x11a7): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `__device_stub__Z11mapStepCUDAPfS_S_ii(float*, float*, float*, int, int)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8cd): multiple definition of `__device_stub__Z11mapStepCUDAPfS_S_ii(float*, float*, float*, int, int)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x12fa): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-29_parallel.o: In function `__device_stub__Z14reduceStepCUDAPfS_ii(float*, float*, int, int)':
tmpxft_00007384_00000000-9_parallel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x9e8): multiple definition of `__device_stub__Z14reduceStepCUDAPfS_ii(float*, float*, int, int)'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1415): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-30_utils.o: In function `_copyHostDevice':
utils.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_copyHostDevice'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x16): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-30_utils.o: In function `_copyDeviceHost':
utils.c:(.text+0x76): multiple definition of `_copyDeviceHost'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8c): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-30_utils.o: In function `getGlobalDim':
utils.c:(.text+0xd7): multiple definition of `getGlobalDim'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xed): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-30_utils.o: In function `getGridBasedOnBlockSize':
utils.c:(.text+0x11d): multiple definition of `getGridBasedOnBlockSize'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x120): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-30_utils.o: In function `_sleep':
utils.c:(.text+0x1a5): multiple definition of `_sleep'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1de): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-30_utils.o: In function `drawMatrix':
utils.c:(.text+0x1c3): multiple definition of `drawMatrix'
/tmp/tmpxft_00007384_00000000-21_nn.o:tmpxft_00007384_00000000-4_nn.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `return dim3(...);` works fine for me. Are you doing this in a `.cu` file or a `.cpp` file?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
You mean the first way?
Well it's a little bit complicated.
I have 3 files, 2 .cu and 1 .c

None .cpp files.
The main function is in a .cu file.
And I have some helper functions in that .c file, in which I also have some cuda coding. This .c file I include in the other .cu files, so its code is processed indeed by nvcc.
But for some reason, even though I have fixed other errors, this keeps popping up.
Should I pass any parameters in nvcc command?
Do you have any suggestion or idea why this is happening?
What do these errors mean?

Comment: Post your files if you're allowed.

Comment: Edit your question to include a complete code that demonstrates the compile error.  It shouldn't take 3 files to demonstrate this, and you should be easily able to include this in the question itself, not in an external link.  Also show the exact nvcc compile command you issue and the exact error output.

Comment: You are trying to compile C++ with a C compiler. That obviously isn't going to ever work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
dim3 gridXY(gridX, gridY);
```

with:

```
dim3 gridXY;
gridXY.x = gridX, gridXY.y = gridY;
```

Comment: See my Edit1 section in original post for my answer, was way too long for comment...

Comment: @BabisI You're including function definitions as header files, of course it's going to give 'multiple definitions' error. Declare all the functions in the `util.c` file in a `util.h` file and include that header in the rest of your files.

Comment: How come `dim3` have only two components `gridX` and `gridY`?